# VBScript/HTA - Using WMI to search registry

Tags: vbscript, registry, wmi, hta

I'm running into an interesting problem when I attempt to run VBScript code from within an HTA application.  Specifically, when I query the Registry using WMI.  Below is the VBscript (within .HTA file) code I am using to determing instance names of SQL server installations:

```
<script language="VBScript">
    Sub searchRegistry
        Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

        strComputer = "."

        Set oReg=GetObject( "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
        strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"
        oReg.EnumValues HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrValueNames, arrValueTypes

        msgbox "SQL Instances already installed: "
        For i=0 To UBound(arrValueNames)
            msgbox arrValueNames(i)     
        Next
    End Sub
```

Null is returned and the loop throws a bound error.  However, when I run this same code from an independent VBScript (.vbs) file it returns the proper values no problem.  I assume this is a permissions issue but don't know where to start; don't know how to give windows HTA files permission to use WMI to search registry.  Moreover, I am able to use WMI from HTA to do other things (get drive space, etc.) without issue so it must be registry restrictions?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of toiling, I've figured it out...

On some 64-bit systems, HTA is incorrectly associated with the 32-bit MSHTA version (%windir%\SYSWOW64\mshta.exe) - resulting in only being able to access certain WMI classes.

In this case, add the path to the proper (64-bit) MSHTA to the command line.  Example:  "%windir%\system32\mshta.exe" "c:\whatever.hta" and the HTA should run with full access to WMI.

Answer (score 0):

As per  [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(VS.85).aspx#Security) , Windows do allow HTA to update registry.

If it does not work for you, It could be related to your 'User Account Control' settings. Disable and try!